# Codeigniter individual passing data from controller to model

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

Im new for CI, as MVC I think my code is not good.

My Controller:

```
public function index(){
    $this->data->report = $this->order_m->get_report();
    parent::_view('report/list',$this->data);
}
```

My Model

```
public function get_report(){

//somecode

if ($this->input->post('submit')){
   $start_date = $this->input->post('thn_start').'-'.$this->input->post('bln_start').'-01';
   $end_date = $this->input->post('thn_end').'-'.$this->input->post('bln_end').'-31';;
} else {
   $start_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-62 day"));
   $end_date = date('Y-m-d');
}
$this->db->where('date_in BETWEEN "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date)). '" and "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end_date)).'"');
$this->db->order_by('id_order','desc');

//somecode

}
```

How I can make this code for MVC style? Thanks

Comment: Why not try reading [the documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html) and following [the tutorial](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html) first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest you to put

```
//somecode

if ($this->input->post('submit')){
   $start_date = $this->input->post('thn_start').'-'.$this->input->post('bln_start').'-01';
   $end_date = $this->input->post('thn_end').'-'.$this->input->post('bln_end').'-31';;
} else {
   $start_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-62 day"));
   $end_date = date('Y-m-d');
}
```

In the controler and pass and pass `$start_date` and `$end_date` to `get_report()` function.
You will have your code as this:

**Controller**

```
public function index(){
    //somecode

    if ($this->input->post('submit')){
       $start_date = $this->input->post('thn_start').'-'.$this->input->post('bln_start').'-01';
       $end_date = $this->input->post('thn_end').'-'.$this->input->post('bln_end').'-31';;
    } else {
       $start_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-62 day"));
       $end_date = date('Y-m-d');
    }
    $data['report'] = $this->order_m->get_report($start_date,$end_date);
    $this->load->view('report/list',$data,1);
}
```

**Model**

```
public function get_report($start_date,$end_date){

//somecode
$this->db->where('date_in BETWEEN "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date)). '" and "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end_date)).'"');
$this->db->order_by('id_order','desc');

//somecode

}
```

Why didn't you use `load->view`?

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
$data = array(
'start' => $this->input->post('thn_start'),
'end' => $this->input->post('thn_end')
);

$result = $this->your_model->get_report($data); // this sends data to model
$this->load->view('report/list', $result);
```

You get Form information in your controller and then send it to model to make some calculation or what ever and return it to controller and pass it to your view.

I hope it helps